# I want to get XML with header <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

On serializing an XmlSerializer object using below code I am getting

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
```

Code:

```
private static bool StudentsReport(string filePath, Students std)
{
       XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        };

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer , std, namespaces );
        }

        return true;
 }
```

Student Class is :

```
public class Students
{
        private string studentID;
        private string studentName;

        /// <summary>
        /// To store Machine Details.
        /// </summary>
        public string ID
        {
            get { return this.studentID; }
            set { this.studentID = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.studentName; }
            set { this.studentName = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Above code is generating XML without standalone

Answer (score 1):

Add the `standalone` value using the `WriteStartDocument` method.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    //OmitXmlDeclaration = true, // must be false
};

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument(standalone: true);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, std, namespaces);
}
```

---

Some tips.

Rename the `Students` class to `Student`. Because it describes a single student, not a collection.

`ID` property rename to `Id`. See [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Change the method signature: `void StudentReport`. It doesn't make sense to always return the same bool value.